# Split Start and end date using Given Dates

Tags: postgresql

I have below scenarios and need to create the efficient query. I can used the procedure or function but need to create query instead of procedure and function.

```
INPUT : 

ID   Start_Dt    End_Dt     Split_Dt
1   01-06-2020  30-06-2020  03-06-2020
2   15-07-2020  30-10-2020  12-08-2020
3   10-04-2020  20-05-2020  20-05-2020
4   20-04-2020  20-05-2020  20-04-2020


Scenario_1
Start_Date : 01-06-2020
End_Date   : 30-06-2020
Split_Date : 03-06-2020

Scenario_2
Start_Date : 15-07-2020
End_Date   : 30-10-2020
Split_Date : 12-08-2020

Output:

ID   Start_Dt   End_Dt      Split_Dt
1   01-06-2020  03-06-2020  2020-06-03
1   04-06-2020  30-06-2020  2020-06-03
2   01-06-2020  12-08-2020  2020-06-03
2   13-08-2020  30-10-2020  2020-06-03
3   10-04-2020  20-05-2020  20-05-2020
4   20-04-2020  20-05-2020  20-04-2020
```

Comment: Is the output for scenario 1 or 2?

Comment: yes..the output of ID 1,2,3,4

Comment: So you want the **same** output for two different sets of input values?

Comment: Yes.based on split_dt column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a mistake in the first record of `ID = 2` in your sample output.

If that is a mistake, then this query should work:

```
select id, start_dt, split_dt 
  from date_splits
 where start_dt < split_dt
union all
select id, split_dt + 1, end_dt
  from date_splits
 where split_dt + 1 < end_dt
order by id, start_dt;
```